# how to configure solr / lucene to perform levenshtein edit distance searching?

Tags: lucene, solr, levenshtein-distance

i have a long list of words that i put into a very simple SOLR / Lucene database. my goal is to find 'similar' words from the list for single-term queries, where 'similarity' is specifically understood as (damerau) levensthein edit distance. i understand SOLR provides such a distance for spelling suggestions.

in my SOLR `schema.xml`, i have configured a field type `string`:

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

which i use to define a field

```
<field name='term' type='string' indexed='true' stored='true' required='true'/>
```

i want to search this field and have results returned according to their levenshtein edit distance. however, when i run a query like `webspace~0.1` against SOLR with debugging and explanations on, the report shows that a whole bunch of considerations went into calculating the scores, e.g.:

```
"1582":"
1.1353534 = (MATCH) sum of:
  1.1353534 = (MATCH) weight(term:webpage^0.8148148 in 1581), product of:
    0.08618848 = queryWeight(term:webpage^0.8148148), product of:
      0.8148148 = boost
      13.172914 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=386954)
      0.008029869 = queryNorm
    13.172914 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(term:webpage in 1581), product of:
      1.0 = tf(termFreq(term:webpage)=1)
      13.172914 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=386954)
      1.0 = fieldNorm(field=term, doc=1581)
```

clearly, for my application, term frequencies, `idf`s and so on are meaningless, as each document only contains a single term. i tried to use the spelling suggestions component, but didn't manage to make it return the actual similarity scores.

can anybody provide hints how to configure SOLR to perform levensthein / jaro-winkler / n-gram searches with scores returned and *without* doing additional stuff like `tf`, `idf`, `boost` and so included? is there a bare-bones configuration sample for SOLR somewhere? i find the number of options truly daunting.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using a nightly build, then you can sort results based on levenshtein distance using the strdist function:

```
q=term:webspace~0.1&sort=strdist("webspace", term, edit) desc
```

More details [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Sort_By_Function) and [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#strdist)

Comment: Just to add that for Solr versions older than 3.1 this is true for all release versions, no need to be running a nightly build any more.

Answer (score 2):

Solr/Lucene doesn't appear to be a good fit for this application. You are likely better off. with [SimMetrics library](http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/simmetrics.html) . It offers a comprehensive set of string-distance calculators incl. Jaro-Winkler, Levenstein etc.

Comment: this is a very interesting link indeed. i wish there was a standard library as comprehensive like this for python as well. unfortunately, since i have to search over hundreds of thousands of words, a solution without indexing will likely be too slow (but i would have to try first). also, i am not quite sure how to integrate a java library into my python project. maybe via HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

> how to configure SOLR to perform levensthein / jaro-winkler / n-gram
>   searches with scores returned and without doing additional stuff like
>   tf, idf, boost and so included?

You've got some solutions of how to obtain the desired results but none actually answeres your question.

`q={!func}strdist("webspace",term,edit)` will overwrite the default document scoring with the Levenstein distance and `q={!func}strdist("webspace",term,jw)` does the same for Jaro-Winkler.

The sorting suggested above will work fine in most cases but it doesn't change  the scoring function, it just sorts the results obtained with the scoring method you want to avoid. This might lead to different results and the order of the groups might not be the same.

To see which ones would fit best a `&debugQuery=true` might be enough.